# Create Rule to Save Attachment to Network Drive

Tags: email, outlook, imap, pop3

I want to create a rule to save Outlook email attachments to a network drive - this needs to occur even if the desktop app is turned off - so I'm assuming that the rule needs to come from the server side. The Outlook desktop application is currently a MAPI architecture.

Our emails are accessible through the web with Office 365. When I go there, I can create "Inbox Rules" - but my options are limited to:

- Move, Copy, or Delete
- Pin the message
- Mark the message
- Forward, redirect, or send

The move, copy or delete tab gives me the option to copy the message to folders within my Outlook account (different inboxes, etc) or to send/copy to one of my contacts, but I need to send the attachment of the message to a directory on a network drive.

Is this possible through Office 365? All of these options regard the message, but I need to work with the attachment. Also, is there a way to send it to a network drive directory instead of contacts or folders? Do I need to contact the network admin and make these adjustments directly on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Server based rule obviously cannot access your folder. You are only limited to the actions that work only with the mailbox and its object's.